# Yii Booster and jQuery UI compatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, yii, slider

i use Yii 1.1.13 and Yii Booster 1.0.6

On one page i need to use TbButtonGroup with checkbox toggle and jQRangeSlider (http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/)

To use slider, i need to include jQuery UI lib, BUT when i include it, the checkbox mode of buttonGroup does not works.

With some versions of UI it just does not work, with with the latest it writes in console on TbButtonGroup click:

```
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on button prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'toggle'
```

The full list of sources is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/baec16ac/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/baec16ac/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/baec16ac/css/font-awesome.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/baec16ac/css/bootstrap-yii.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/baec16ac/css/jquery-ui-bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/baec16ac/css/bootstrap-notify.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jqslider/iThing-min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/b1075121/jquery.yiiactiveform.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/b1075121/jquery.ba-bbq.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/baec16ac/js/bootstrap.bootbox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/baec16ac/js/bootstrap.notify.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/baec16ac/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=places&amp;language=en"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jqslider/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jqslider/jQAllRangeSliders-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/search.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.js"></script>
```

If i delete the jquery ui, where is no slider, but all works fine. Help me please, where is the bug?

Comment: Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on button prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'toggle'

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to manually include your whatever scripts you need, using Yii::app()->clientScript
its safe becuz Yii wont load duplicate scipts

Comment: Just tested this on clean install of latest versions of Booster and Yii. On the pages with jQuery UI, buttonGroup checkbox mode doesn't work.